# How to append a dictionary to a json file in Python?

Tags: python, json

I want to read a json file in Python and add content to the file respecting the json format, but I can't manage to do it.

The json file "paises.json" :

```
 {
  "España": [
    {
      "Superficie": 505944,
      "Población": 47450795
    }
  ],
  "Francia": [
    {
      "Superficie": 675417,
      "Población": 67407241
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to read that file in Python and append new content to it. The code is:

```
import json

with open("paises.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as paises:
    datos = json.load(paises)
print(datos.keys())  # Show dictionary

nombre_pais = input("\nIndique el nombre del país\n")
nueva_superficie = float(input("\nIndique la superficie\n"))
nueva_poblacion = int(input("\nIndique la Población\n"))
nuevo_contenido = {nombre_pais: {"Superficie": nueva_superficie, "Población": nueva_poblacion}}

datos.update(nuevo_contenido)
print(datos)  # Show dictionary with new content

with open("paises.json", "a", encoding="utf-8") as paises:
    json.dump(nuevo_contenido, paises)
```

The result is not what I have expected:

```
{
  "España": [
    {
      "Superficie": 505944,
      "Población": 47450795
    }
  ],
  "Francia": [
    {
      "Superficie": 675417,
      "Población": 67407241
    }
  ]
}
{"Portugal": {"Superficie":  92090, "Poblaci\u00f3n":   10295909}}
```

The formatting is not correct, a comma and a square bracket are missing and the coding of the accents is not ok.

What can I do to correct it?

Thank you

Comment: Just insert `nombre_pais` into the `datos` dict e.g. `datos[nombre_pais] = {"Superficie": nueva_superficie, ... }` and then dump `datos` to the JSON file.

Comment: Not sure about the accents, but instead of `append`, try: `datos[nombre_pais] = [{"Superficie": nueva_superficie, "Población": nueva_poblacion}]`

Comment: In addition to the other remarks: With `with open("paises.json", "a", ...)` you open the file for _appending_, i.e. you just paste the new content below the old one.

Comment: you have to load old file to memory, add new values to data in memory, and write all data back to file (in write mode, not in append mode) - it meas to write `datos`. You can't append to existing file because it create incorrect JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can't append new data directly to JSON file because it creates incorrect JSON.
(Exception can be when you want to create `multi-JSON` file)

With normal JSON you have to:

- read all data from file to memory,
- append new values in memory,
- write back all data (`datos`) from memory to file in `"write mode"`, not `"append mode"`.

```
with open("paises.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as paises:
    json.dump(datos, paises)
```